# Compute the inertia of a sparse matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I want to compute reasonably fast the inertia (triplet of integers representing the number of 1> positive, 2> negative and 3> null eigenvalues) of a sparse real symmetric ***(N x N)*** matrix ***M*** in Python (***N*** between 100 and 100000).

I already have a "solution" by converting ***M*** back to a dense form, and then using ***numpy.linalg.eigvalsh(M)*** to compute the whole spectrum, which then makes the inertia obvious to calculate.

However I would like to keep the problem sparse for speed consideration, as I have to carry out this computation countless times.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142549/calculating-the-inertia-of-a-real-symmetric-or-tridiagonal-matrix) provided a good start, I am now looking for an existing efficient python implementation applicable to a sparse symmetric matrix, or for any hint on how to proceed.

In particular, any decomposition of the matrix that would also help solve ***Mx = b*** for ***x*** (***b*** known) would be welcome as I also have to do that before calculating the inertia of ***M***.